# Track user when connecting with ssh

Tags: unix, ssh

I am a user with `local` as my username to the server `localServer`. I have a database server say `DBServer` and the username to connect through ssh is `dbuser`. I can only connect to `DBServer` through `localServer`. So I need to login to `localServer` with `local` user and then connect to `DBServer` with `dbuser`. Is there any chance that ADMIN of `DBServer` can track `local` user?

Answer (score 0):

dbuser has to connect to localServer to check what local user is doing or done. Since you connect to DBServer with dbuser there is no information about local user withing DBServer. So the short answer is no.